# Laravel 5.3: delete image from storage

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I have a method which deletes a product and image that belongs to it, but I can not delete the image.

Where am I going wrong with this?

```
public function deleteProduct($ids)
{
    foreach ($ids as $id => $value) {
        $product = Product::find($id);
        $productImage = $product->image_path;
        if ($productImage) {
            Storage::delete($productImage);
            $product->destroy($id);
        }
    }
}
```

I have a symlink between storage and public folder.

Under storage images are located at e.g. - storage/app/public/images/products/4/image.png

Under public - public/storage/images/products/4/imagep.png

Image path is stored in database as - /storage/images/products/4/ACTCMRcYlWR8Bn3ZxoJ7bpiDJ7.png

Comment: What is the error you are getting from this block of code ?

Comment: @Minhajul no errors. It just deletes the product, but not the image.

Comment: Have you tried with File::delete($filename); this ?

Comment: @Minhajul Yes, same result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had to add remove '/storage' part of the path and prepend '/public'.

`$productImage = str_replace('/storage', '', $product->image_path);`

`Storage::delete('/public' . $productImage);`

Comment: this might be helpful: Storage::disk('public')->delete("folder_path" . $productImage);

Answer (score 1):

If you added /storage part to the path you can use file system:

```
if (File::exists(public_path($image->path))) {
            File::delete(public_path($image->path));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write something like this in my Model or helper and call it whenever I want:

```
public static function delete_file($path)
{
    if (\Storage::disk('public')->exists($path))
        \Storage::disk('public')->delete($path);
}
```