# How to delete the image from the storage in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am currently trying to delete an image when a user updates his/her post before publishing.

Everything works fine, the image is changed in the database and post page, but I want to delete the previous image.

### Here is my controller

```
public function updatePost(Request $request){
    $data = $request->all();
    $postid = $request['id'];
    $isExist = Post::where('id', $postid)->first();
    if($isExist){
        if ($request->hasFile('image')) {

            $file = $request->File('image');
            //Get filename with extension
            $fileNameToStoreWithExt = $file[0]->getClientOriginalName();
            //Get just filename
            $filename = pathinfo($fileNameToStoreWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            //Get just ext
            $extension = $file[0]->getClientOriginalExtension();
            //File to store
            $fileNameToStore = $filename . '_' . time() . '.' . $extension;
            //Upload Image
            $path = $file[0]->storeAs('image', $fileNameToStore);
            $file[0]->move('storage/image', $fileNameToStore);
            File::delete(public_path('storage/image'.$isExist['image']));
            Post::where('id', $postid)->update([
                'title' => $data['title'],
                'category' => $data['category'],
                'content' => $data['content'],
                'image' => $path
            ]);
            return response()->json([
                'status'=>'200',
                'response'=> 'successfully updated'
            ]);
        }else{
            Post::where('id', $postid)->update([
                'title' => $data['title'],
                'category' => $data['category'],
                'content' => $data['content']
            ]);
            return response()->json([
                'status'=>'200',
                'response'=> 'successfully updated'
            ]);
        }
    }else{
        return response()->json([
            'error'=> 'post does not exist'
        ]);
    }
}
```

I used:

> File::delete(public_path('storage/image'.$isExist['image']));

but it didn't do the job

my delete function

```
       public function deletePost($id){
        $post = Post::where('id',$id)->first();
//        dd($post);
        if(!$post){
            return response()->json([
                'status' => '500',
                'error' => 'post not found'
            ]);
        }
        Storage::disk('public')->delete('/storage/image'. $post['image']);
        Post::where('id', $id)->delete();
        return response()->json([
            'status'=> '200',
            'response'=> 'Post successfully deleted'
        ]);
    }
```

my storage path snapshot[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to unlink image in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713888/how-to-unlink-image-in-php)

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/43706241/12232340

Comment: `$file_path =public_path('/images/') .$banners->photo;
                    if(file_exists($file_path)){
                    unlink($file_path);
                    }`

Comment: @PHPNinja no it didnt

Comment: @Dlk the solutions didnt solve my issue

Answer (score 4):

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

Storage::delete('file.jpg'); // delete file from default disk

Storage::delete(['file.jpg', 'file2.jpg']); // delete multiple files         

Storage::disk('your_disk')->delete('file.jpg'); // delete file from specific disk e.g; s3, local etc
```

Please refer link https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/filesystem

Comment: turned out this didnt work out for me. check the question update. the image should help

Comment: try with public_path("storage/images/".$post['image'])

Answer (score 2):

If you look at laravel file-system [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/filesystem#deleting-files) you will see there are multiple Disk laravel support. you can used Storage Facades to delete a file from Storage like this

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
Storage::disk('local')->delete('folder_path/file_name.jpg');
```

path should be like this for public directory.

```
 Storage::disk('local')->delete('public/image/'.$filename);
```

Comment: turned out this didnt work out for me. check the question update. the image should help

Comment: path should be like this for public directory Storage::disk('local')->delete('public/image/'.$post['image']);

Answer (score 2):

its easy to do an if statement and delete old image on updating! this code is an example edit it to your requirements.

```
if ($request->hasFile('file')) {
    Storage::delete($myImage->file); // If $file is path to old image

    $myImage->file= $request->file('file')->store('name-of-folder');
}
```

Another :

```
File::delete(public_path('images/'. $oldFilename));
```

see here : https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/delete-old-image-from-public-folder-after-updating

Answer (score 1):

You can use normal PHP delete file keyword @unlink

```
if (file_exists($image)) {
  @unlink($image);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `File` to delete file from specific path

```
 $file= "image path here";
 \File::delete($file);
```

[Delete uploaded file from public dir](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/delete-uploaded-file-from-public-dir)

**OR**

You can use `unlink` for the same

```
$image_path = "image path here"; 

 if (file_exists($image_path)) {

       @unlink($image_path);

   }
```

[PHP -> unlink](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php)